# Creating Native Like OffCanvas Menu using Angularjs/Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-touch

This is just a question but i would like to know if there are any angularjs/bootstrap modules which helps me achieve the following

1. on touching the screen edges the menu popup up just like we have in native slider menu UI(off canvas Menu)
2. while touching opening menu  and dragging menu pos based on touch pos only.
3. using touch slide (left or right) to open menus.
4. based on swipe or touch or drag open menu

I have seen ngAside 
http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAside
http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/

Apart from this are there any other framework which helpe me achive theabove points.